# Globalization problem with DateTime and ASP.NET MVC 3 Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

My application runs under ro-RO culture settings, configured in web.config globalization section. If I make a POST request like

```
POST /myapp/index
date=03-12-2010&value=something
```

the model binding maps this to correct date value of "03 December 2010", since the default datetime format for ro-RO culture is dd-MM-yyyy. If I change the request method to GET passing the same data the date value in my action becomes "12 March 2010" (MM-dd-yyyy datetime format)

```
GET /myapp/index?date=03-12-2010&value=something

$.getJSON('/Home/Index', $('form').serialize(), function(d) {
            // ...
});
$.post('/Home/Index', $('form').serialize(), function(d) {
            // ...
}, 'json');
```

So in this case "getJson" & "post" must return the same result, but I get different results because of datetime difference.

How can I enable the same parsing format for GET requests also?

I know I can use a more generic format such as yyyy-MM-dd for dates, but I am just curious why is this happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my previous answer on this subject: [Nullable DateTime Parameter is never bound when calling the action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753569/nullable-datetime-parameter-is-never-bound-when-calling-the-action/3753829#3753829)

"*This is intentional. Anything that is part of the URI (note the 'Uniform' in URI) is interpreted as if it were coming from the invariant culture. This is so that a user in the U.S. who copies a link and sends it over IM to a friend in the U.K. can be confident that his friend will see the exact same page (as opposed to an HTTP 500 due to a DateTime conversion error, for example). **In general, dates passed in RouteData or QueryString should be in the format yyyy-mm-dd so as to be unambiguous across cultures**.*

*If you need to interpret a QueryString or RouteData parameter in a culture-aware manner, pull it in as a string, then convert it to the desired type manually, passing in the desired culture. (DateTime.Parse has overloads that allow you to specify a culture.) If you do this, I recommend also taking the desired culture as a QueryString or a RouteData parameter so that the 'Uniform' part of URI isn't lost, e.g. the URL will look something like ...?culture=fr-fr&date=01-10-1990.*"