# MVC3 Date in UK Format not received on Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Given this VM

```
public class ApplicationDTO : BaseDTO
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int JobId {get;set;}
    public int Status {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ExpertCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have a hidden field thusly

```
@Html.Hidden("Date", DateTime.Now)
```

Which fiddler shows me is sent to the server as I would expect (UK format, I'm in the UK!)

[image]

But on the controller the date shows as being the default min. date

[image]

Is it just the UK format? If so, what is my best way round it? Whilst currently I am setting it to the current date, potentially it could be set to any given date i.e.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Date)
```

I am using AJAX to submit the form, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Post Or Get? I believe for Get. For Get MVC uses the culture invariant format (basically US, but also accepts yyyy-mm-dd). See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349589/globalization-problem-with-datetime-and-asp-net-mvc-3-model-binding

Comment: You are correct, it is a GET. Aha. So sounds like I need to set the culture.

Comment: No setting the culture won't help. All Gets uses the culture invariant format or you couldn't pass querystrings around. You have to write a custom model binder if you want to avoud that behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a Get MVC uses culture invariant format (Basically US format) by default during model binding. So it doesn't accept UK date format. I believe the design reasons are that a querystring could be passed around so therefore it needs to be culture invariant (I wasn't 100% convinced by that logic).

This article covers a possible solution http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/localization-of-dates-in-asp-net-mvc/

We just make sure we never do a Get with a UK date format

This questions also covers the issue [Globalization problem with DateTime and ASP.NET MVC 3 Model Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349589/globalization-problem-with-datetime-and-asp-net-mvc-3-model-binding)

Comment: I can use Html.Hidden("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")) and it binds correctly. This is fine for me in my context as the user doesn't need to see this date (hence hidden). Thanks!

Comment: Cool glad to help. I hated dealing with this throughout our application :). Easier when you are doing Ajax and you don't have to worry about them seeing the values.

Comment: Indeed, it does mean there is a rather interesting bridge to cross further down the line when we have to show dates in UK and send back as yyyy/mm/dd. Guess the answer is to intercept the get, manually convert the date and send it on to the server. Fun.

Answer (score 1):

you should use Data Annotation for Formatting the date on your Model or View model

```
public class ApplicationDTO : BaseDTO
{
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public int JobId {get;set;}
   public int Status {get;set;}
   [Required]
   public string Message { get; set; }
   public string ExpertCode { get; set; }
}
```

Apply the format according you.
As i have seen you are not providing any format to your property

Comment: Still arrives at the server a min. datetime value

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with dd.MM.yyyy format and had to set globalization element in web.config to appropriate culture and uiCulture attribute settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you use @Html.Hidden (not the For helper) it won't be able to match the parameter in the request to the property in your model.

If you use @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Date, "28/2/2013") you will see the date populated appropriately.

Also you can verify the Request.Params collection. Put a break point in the Action. You'll see that one of the Params has your date.... JQuery does not affect this in any way.

Comment: So long as the name HTML property matches, it will bind. It does this with all the other properties on the vm above.