# MVC Date Time Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, custom-model-binder, kendo-datepicker

I am using 2 kendo date pickers in my application as such:

```
<div class="span12">
    <div class="span2" style="text-align: right">
        Start Date:
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m=>m.StartDate))
    </div>
    <div class="span2" style="text-align: right">
        End Date:
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m=>m.EndDate))
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getGraphData()">Show</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the button is clicked, I read the values of these date pickers client side and make a POST to a API controller.

The issue I am having is sometimes the DateTime parameters are parsed incorrectly, I am using a en-GB culture (specified in my web.config), however given a date of 01/03/2014 (1st March), when the value is processed by the model binder, it is interpreted as  03/01/2014 (3rd Jan).

My javascript is as follows:

```
function getGraphData() {

        var startDatePicker = $("#StartDate").data("kendoDatePicker");
        var endDatePicker = $("#EndDate").data("kendoDatePicker");
        var param = {
            StartDate: kendo.toString(startDatePicker.value().toLocaleDateString(), "dd/MM/yyyy"),
            EndDate: kendo.toString(endDatePicker.value().toLocaleDateString(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
        };
       // Do post here

    }
```

My model is as follows:

```
public class DateRangeParam
    {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DateRangeParam"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public DateRangeParam()
        {
            this.EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
            this.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets or sets the end date.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets or sets the start date.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

I figured the solutions was that I needed a custom model binder to parse the datetime value, so I created on (as follows) and registered it in the Global.asax.cs file, but this didnt work, the binder is never called, I am unsure if this is because the datetime is a property of a custom object.

```
 public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        #region Fields


        private readonly string _customFormat;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors and Destructors

       public DateTimeModelBinder(string customFormat)
        {
            this._customFormat = customFormat;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Explicit Interface Methods

        object IModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            return DateTime.ParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, this._customFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And it is registered as follows:

```
var binder = new DateTimeModelBinder(new CultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), binder);
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), binder);
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Well known behaviour.

[See this stack overflow post][1]

[or this one][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147467/mvc3-date-in-uk-format-not-received-on-controller
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349589/globalization-problem-with-datetime-and-asp-net-mvc-3-model-binding

Comment: While I understand that this is a well known issue, I am unsure of why my custom binder is not even called.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I didn't see was where you registered your DateTimeModelBinder in your global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(DateTime)] = 
           new DateAndTimeModelBinder() { CustomFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd" };
```

[Scott Hanselman has this very similar post working with DateTime Custom Model Binders](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this, what I eventually did was post the parameter to the controller as a UTC timestamp, and boom, MVC automatically converts the timestamp to a valid date time so my model binds nicely :)