# MVC Action DateTime Parameter Format With Ajax URL Parameters

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I am sending `ajax` request and parameters in `url` one of which is `date`. The `format` in url looks like `dd.mm.yyyy`. When goes in controller `DateTime` parameter reads it as `mm/DD/yyyy`. How can I change this `behaviour` and tell mvc to read it as `dd/MM/yyyy` ?

**Example:**

```
URL: 12.01.2017

MVC: 01.12.2017
```

Comment: you have to create your cutom model binder... 
follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425719/mvc-date-time-model-binding

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using (asp.net-mvc?)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the configuration that you have on your browser for the culture, unless you POST the data in the format you want.

On IE, 
Click Internet Options.
Click Languages, under the General tab.
Click Add...
Select the language you would like to add.
Click OK.

Then move the language that you want up to have the priority over the others, the Culture will come from there and the date format will change.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the format attribute in the constructor of your datetimepicker assuming you are using jquery.

For example:

$('.datepicker').datepicker({ "format": 'dd/mm/yyyy' });